# How do I convert _m128i to an unsigned int with SSE?

Tags: c++, image-processing, sse, simd

I have made a function for posterizing images.

```
// =(
#define ARGB_COLOR(a, r, g, b) (((a) << 24) | ((r) << 16) | ((g) << 8) | (b))

inline UINT PosterizeColor(const UINT &color, const float &nColors)
{
    __m128 clr = _mm_cvtepi32_ps(  _mm_cvtepu8_epi32((__m128i&)color)  );

    clr = _mm_mul_ps(clr,  _mm_set_ps1(nColors / 255.0f)  );
    clr = _mm_round_ps(clr, _MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT);
    clr = _mm_mul_ps(clr, _mm_set_ps1(255.0f / nColors)  );

    __m128i iClr = _mm_cvttps_epi32(clr);

    return ARGB_COLOR(iClr.m128i_u8[12],
                      iClr.m128i_u8[8],
                      iClr.m128i_u8[4],
                      iClr.m128i_u8[0]);
}
```

in the first line, I unpack the color into 4 floats, but I can't find the proper way to do the reverse.

I searched through the SSE docs and could not find the reverse of `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32`

does one exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no instruction to do that even in AVX (none that I'm aware of). So you will have to do it manually like are right now.

However, your current method is very sub-optimal and you're relying on `.m128i_u8` which is an MSVC extension. Based on my experience with MSVC, it will use an aligned buffer to access the individual elements. This has a very heavy penalty because of partial-word access.

Instead of `.m128i_u8`, use [`_mm_extract_epi32()`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse41_reg_ins_ext.htm). This is in SSE4.1. But you're already relying with SSE4.1 with `_mm_cvtepu8_epi32()`.

This situation is particularly bad since you're working with 1-byte granularity. If you were working with 2-byte (16-bit integer) granularity instead, there is an efficient solution using [shuffle intrinsics](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011/compiler_c/intref_cls/common/intref_sse2_misc.htm).

Comment: _mm_extract_epi32() helped a bit, but what do you mean by "very sub-optimal"?

Comment: Generally speaking, when you store some data and then immediately try to access it again with a different word-size, there will be a huge penalty. From what I've seen, MSVC's method of extracting components of an `xmm` register is to do exactly that: store into memory, and access the words separately. But I guess this particular case isn't the worst case scenario.

Comment: ok, anyways, for a 2048x2048 its running in 22ms, which i suppose is good enough for now. thanks =)

Comment: @Mysticial: those stalls have been dramatically reduced in more recent µarchs.  Consult the Intel Optimization Manual for exactly which cases can forward directly without incurring a stall.

Comment: This answer as it is is misleading for the statement about the impossibility to shuffle.

Answer (score 8):

A combination of `_mm_shuffle_epi8` and `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` is what you need:

```
static const __m128i shuffleMask = _mm_setr_epi8(0,  4,  8, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1,
                                               -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);
UINT color = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(_mm_shuffle_epi8(iClr, shuffleMask));
```

Comment: Small mistake: `_mm_set_epi8` should be `_mm_setr_epi8`. Otherwise, this actually works! I'm amazed, +1. I didn't realize the SSSE3 had a byte-granularity shuffle.

Comment: thanks for this, but I also found that I could do this, which is giving me pretty much the same results as above:
  iClr = _mm_packs_epi32(iClr, _mm_setzero_si128());
  iClr = _mm_packus_epi16(iClr, _mm_setzero_si128());
  UINT color = (UINT)_mm_extract_epi32(iClr, 0); -- I also rewrote the routine using integer math, then converted it to asm, which yielded the best result of 8~9 ms for a 2048x2048 image.