# How to store 4 bytes out of my 16 bytes register after having used intrinsics using up to SSSE3

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

**Preliminary note:** Actually while I was finishing writing the question I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662776/2436175) was addressing my case. Nevertheless, since I have already spent the time to create all the links to the necessary documentation, it might be useful to post it anyway. Furthermore, there might be better answers out there.

**Here is the question:**

At the end of my processing I will have a `__mm128i` containing:

```
r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 rA rB rC rD rE rF
```

I will have to store in memory a `uint32_t` like this:

```
r0 r4 r8 rC
```

Or, alternatively (it just depends on how I perform the last 2 steps of the previous computations)

```
r3 r7 rB rF
```

How can I do it efficiently using up to SSSE3 instructions?

Answer (score 3):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8662776/2436175), using up to SSSE3 instructions, you can use [`_mm_shuffle_epi8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531427%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to have your register rearranged like this:

```
r0 r4 r8 rC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Then, you cannot use [`_mm_extract_epi32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531460%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) because it's SSE4.1

You can use instead [`_mm_cvtsi128_si32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/5z7a9642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).